# Does Picasso caching states of requests?

Tags: android, caching, picasso

My server contains images, which are could not be loading at the moment - back-end returns URL for future image. And somehow happens that when `Picasso` tries to load image at the first time - he stucks with `404` http error. After few seconds image appears on web server and I trying load again, but I either getting `404` error. So the question is simple - does picasso caching requests? Or states of responses?

Schematically it looks like

```
Picasso -> load(URL) -> 404 error - image not exit on web-server

few seconds later

Picasso -> load(URL) -> 404 error - image exist on web-server.
```

Answer (score 0):

Picasso.with(context)
       .load(url)
       .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
       .resize(180, 180)
       .centerCrop()
       .into(iv_profile_pic, new Callback() {};